# Android ndk compiling error: unknown type name 'JNIEnv'

Tags: java-native-interface, android.mk

I am coding in Android studio, would make a .so file . But I cannot resolve this problem . Though I have included  who can help me?

**My jni folder and error info img** :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ankmm.png

**My Android.mk file:**

---

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := swresample-prebuilt 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/libswresample-2.so 
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libswresample include 
$(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ffmpegplay
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := NativeUtil.c FFmpegCodec.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS :=-llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := avcodec-prebuilt avformat-prebuilt swscale-prebuilt avutil-prebuilt  swresample-prebuilt
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: i have include <jni.h> header file

Comment: Please include the code in NativeUtil.c which is referenced in the error messages.

Comment: #include <jni.h>  // 初始化 ffmpeg
jint naInit(JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject pObj, jstring pFileName)
{
    const char *myStr = GetStringUTFChars(pEnv,pFileName,JNI_FALSE);
    LOGD("=====================naInit fileName==%s",myStr );
    ReleaseStringUTFChars(pEnv,pFileName,myStr);
}

Comment: error is the jniEnv  ,i have include the <jni.h>

Comment: Did you installed NDK? And set up Android Studio to point to the directory where NDK is installed?

Comment: yes ,i have already installed ,and i can make the project successfully ,when i removed PREBUILT module.it is  very delusively.  i thought it cannot find the jni.h  path .when i include other header files.

Comment: I have solve it to using  LOCAL_C_INCLUDES to include jni.h  file path in Android.mk . But i really don't like this way.

Comment: mistake using LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES or LOCAL_C_INCLUDES.

Comment: @glenchang I was having the same problem and LOCAL_C_INCLUDES saved me. Thanks!!!

Comment: Dammit, appears I was wrong...